# Message order cascading on " html anchor callback: [ 1 + 1 ]; with: 'Click me' " matters?

Tags: pharo, seaside

In Seaside it seems these two return different results.
First one works and produces a vaild link, the second one doesn't, why does it matter which you send first?

```
html anchor callback: [ 1 + 1 ]; with: 'Click me'.
html anchor with: 'Click me'; callback: [ 1 + 1 ].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best explanation about this can be found in the [Seaside book, section on brush structure](http://book.seaside.st/book/fundamentals/rendering-components/brush-structure).

In Seaside, `with:` should always be the last message in a cascade sent to a brush. This is because the nested renderable that is the argument of `with:` specifies the inner contents of the html tag.

Technically, sending `with:` causes the brush to be written to the canvas. As such, anything you send to the brush afterwards cannot affect the rendered html anymore.

Comment: I agree, however it's interesting that executing " html anchor with: 'Click me' " doesn't actually produce a link at all, it generates <a>Click me</a> which is an anchor to 'nothing' while " html anchor callback: [ ] with: 'Click me' " produces <a href="/app_name?_s=whatever_k=something">Click me</a> It's like callbacks in Seaside are implemented as href urls in HTML, which is true actually.

Comment: callback implementation " self url addField: (self storeCallback: (WAActionCallback on: aBlock)) "